# Update of value in array of jsonb returns error"invalid input syntax for type json"

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column of type `jsonb` which contains json arrays of the form

```json
[
  {
    "Id": 62497,
    "Text": "BlaBla"
  }
]
```

I'd like to update the `Id` to the value of a column `word_id` (type `uuid`) from a different table `word`.

I tried this

```sql
update inflection_copy
SET inflectionlinks = s.json_array
FROM (
        SELECT jsonb_agg(
                CASE
                    WHEN elems->>'Id' = (
                        SELECT word_copy.id::text
                        from word_copy
                        where word_copy.id::text = elems->>'Id'
                    ) THEN jsonb_set(
                        elems,
                        '{Id}'::text [],
                        (
                            SELECT jsonb(word_copy.word_id::text)
                            from word_copy
                            where word_copy.id::text = elems->>'Id'
                        )
                    )
                    ELSE elems
                END
            ) as json_array
        FROM inflection_copy,
            jsonb_array_elements(inflectionlinks) elems
    ) s;
```

Until now I always get the following error:

```
invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "c66a4353" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: c66a4353...
```

The **c66a4535** is part of one of the uuids of the `word` table. I don't understand why this is marked as invalid input.

**EDIT:**

To give an example of one of the uuids:

```sql
select to_jsonb(word_id::text) from word_copy limit(5);
```

returns

```
+----------------------------------------+
| to_jsonb                               |
|----------------------------------------|
| "078c979d-e479-4fce-b27c-d14087f467c2" |
| "ef288256-1599-4f0f-a932-aad85d666c9a" |
| "d1d95b60-623e-47cf-b770-de46b01042c5" |
| "f97464c6-b872-4be8-9d9d-83c0102fb26a" |
| "9bb19719-e014-4286-a2d1-4c0cf7f089fc" |
+----------------------------------------+
```

As requested the respective columns `id` and `word_id` from the `word` table:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| row                                               |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| ('27733', '078c979d-e479-4fce-b27c-d14087f467c2') |
| ('72337', 'ef288256-1599-4f0f-a932-aad85d666c9a') |
| ('72340', 'd1d95b60-623e-47cf-b770-de46b01042c5') |
| ('27741', 'f97464c6-b872-4be8-9d9d-83c0102fb26a') |
| ('72338', '9bb19719-e014-4286-a2d1-4c0cf7f089fc') |
+---------------------------------------------------+


+----------------+----------+----------------------------+
| Column         | Type     | Modifiers                  |
|----------------+----------+----------------------------|
| id             | bigint   |                            |
| value          | text     |                            |
| homonymnumber  | smallint |                            |
| pronounciation | text     |                            |
| audio          | text     |                            |
| level          | integer  |                            |
| alpha          | bigint   |                            |
| frequency      | bigint   |                            |
| hanja          | text     |                            |
| typeeng        | text     |                            |
| typekr         | text     |                            |
| word_id        | uuid     |  default gen_random_uuid() |
+----------------+----------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: try to replace `SELECT jsonb(word_copy.word_id::text)` by `SELECT to_jsonb(word_copy.word_id::text)`

Comment: Then I get the following error ```cannot extract elements from a scalar```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to modify your sub query as follow :

```
update inflection_copy AS ic
SET inflectionlinks = s.json_array
FROM 
(SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN wc.word_id IS NULL THEN e.elems ELSE jsonb_set(e.elems, array['Id'], to_jsonb(wc.word_id::text)) END ORDER BY e.id ASC) AS json_array
   FROM inflection_copy AS ic
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(ic.inflectionlinks, '$[*]') WITH ORDINALITY AS e(elems, id)
   LEFT JOIN word_copy AS wc
     ON wc.id::text = e.elems->>'Id'
) AS s
```

The `LEFT JOIN` clause will return `wc.word_id = NULL` when there is no `wc.id` which corresponds to `e.elems->>'id'`, so that `e.elems` is unchanged in the `CASE`.

The `ORDER BY` clause in the aggregate function `jsonb_agg` will ensure that the order is unchanged in the jsonb array.

`jsonb_path_query` is used instead of `jsonb_array_elements` so that to not raise an error when `ic.inflectionlinks` is not a jsonb array and it is used in lax mode (which is the default behavior).

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ztP7OELF)

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists: ```cannot extract elements from a scalar```

Comment: can you share an extract of your `word_copy` table with both columns `id` & `word_id` with original data types (no conversion) ?

Comment: Please see my edit above

Comment: ok look at the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AvL7XinY) in my updated answer, I don't get your error ... So it comes from somewhere else. I think your error comes from some jsonb values which are not jsonb arrays in your column `inflectionlinks `, and in this case `jsonb_array_elements` raises an error. You can use instead  `jsonb_path_query(ic.inflectionlinks, '$[*]')` which will not raise an error when it is used in lax mode (default behavior).

Comment: There might be null values. How would I test for them? I saw people working with ```type_of_jsonb``` (or something similar). Btw your approach worked so thanks! It still bothers me that I don't fully understand your approach yet.

Comment: You can exlude the NULL values by simply adding the clause `WHERE ic.inflectionlinks IS NOT NULL` but these NULL values should not raise an error. My proposed approach is basic sql query, so it is important that you can understand it. What is unclear for you ?

Comment: What exactly does the ```CROSS LITERAL JOIN``` do? As far as I understand the left join lets us compare ```word.word_copy``` to the ```Id``` field in our JSON.

Comment: For each row of `inflection_copy `, CROSS JOIN is going to unnest the corresponding `inflectionlinks` array and is resulting in as many rows as the length of this array.